# What is meaning of different symbols in image?

Tags: probability, notation

I am learning about Deep Generative Models, tutorials all over the places use symbols and no one actually explaining the meaning of it. Can you please suggest the meaning of these terms?

[image]

Comment: partially answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161808/how-is-the-notation-x-sim-n-mu-sigma2-read/162091#162091

Comment: you can use math typesetting instead of attaching an image. More information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

In statistics, I read the "twiddle" notation ($\sim$) as: "is distributed as". The RHS should be a probability model, or family of distributions thereof. We are left to gather than $p_{data}$ is an unobserved data generating mechanism. But by running some ML-magic, you can get a $p_{model}$ which is a probability model for simulating outcomes. "Want to learn p-model similar to p-data" is just bad English, but the idea is just goodness of fit. Observed should accord with expected.